# Laptop sleeps even though sleep is disabled

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, power-management

I am running Ubuntu on a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 10.

The laptop is being put to sleep after 15 minutes of inactivity even though I have disabled sleep.

In my power management settings I have set sleep laptop and display to 'never' for battery and AC modes.

Is there something else I need to change as well?